# How to scrape data from paginated table?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need your help trying to automate this web page by getting the data of all the players on the different pages.

```
import request
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.mlb.com/es/stats/spring-training'

pagina = requests.get(url2)

soup = BeautifulSoup(pagina.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table', {'class':"bui-table is-desktop-sKqjv9Sb"})


encabezados = []

for i in table.find_all('th')[:18]:
    datos = i.find_all('button')
    for td in datos:
     titulo = td.text.strip()
    encabezados.append(titulo)

datos_mlb = pd.DataFrame(columns = encabezados)


nombres = []

for i in table.find_all('th')[18:]:
    datos = i.find_all('a')
    for td in datos:
     jugadores = td.text.strip() 
    nombres.append(jugadores)
    
datos_mlb['JUGADOR'] = nombres


for fila in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    data = fila.find_all('td')
    data_fila = [td.text.strip() for td in data]
    largo = len(datos_mlb)-1
    datos_mlb.iloc[:,1:] = data_fila
```

I have tried to fit the vast majority of information, however I cannot complete the data correctly and iterate all the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the structured data from JSON response of XHR request to create your `dataframe`. Inspect network tab in your browsers devtools, to get an idea, what parameters you should send and what you will get:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

data = []

for i in range(0,175,25):
    data.extend(
        requests.get(
            f'https://bdfed.stitch.mlbinfra.com/bdfed/stats/player?stitch_env=prod&season=2022&sportId=1&stats=season&group=hitting&gameType=S&limit=25&offset={i}&sortStat=onBasePlusSlugging&order=desc', 
            headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
        ).json()['stats']
    )
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | playerId | playerName | ... | type | atBatsPerHomeRun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 502671 | Paul Goldschmidt | ... | player | 5.5 |
| 1 | 621439 | Byron Buxton | ... | player | 6.4 |
| 2 | 547180 | Bryce Harper | ... | player | 4.38 |
| 3 | 658668 | Edward Olivares | ... | player | 11.33 |
| 4 | 670351 | Jose Rojas | ... | player | 9 |
| ... |  | ... |  | ... |  |  |  |
| 156 | 593871 | Jorge Polanco | ... | player | 32.00 |
| 157 | 676475 | Alec Burleson | ... | player | -.-- |
| 158 | 608385 | Jesse Winker | ... | player | -.-- |
| 159 | 641355 | Cody Bellinger | ... | player | -.-- |
| 160 | 660162 | Yoan Moncada | ... | player | -.-- |

[161 rows x 72 columns]

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting all the required data because data is loaded dynamically via API.So you have to pull data from API.

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
api_url = 'https://bdfed.stitch.mlbinfra.com/bdfed/stats/player?stitch_env=prod&season=2022&sportId=1&stats=season&group=hitting&gameType=S&limit=161&offset=0&sortStat=onBasePlusSlugging&order=desc'  
req = requests.get(api_url).json()

data =[]
for item in req['stats']:
    playerName=item['playerName']
    data.append({
        'playerName':playerName
        })

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
        playerName
0    Paul Goldschmidt
1        Byron Buxton
2        Bryce Harper
3     Edward Olivares
4          Jose Rojas
..                ...
156     Jorge Polanco
157     Alec Burleson
158      Jesse Winker
159    Cody Bellinger
160      Yoan Moncada

[161 rows x 1 columns]
```